# Hints on calculating an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, normed-spaces

Suppose $x(t)$ and $y(t')$ are curves traversing the boundary of $[0,1]^2$ in $R^2$ counterclockwise. What is the integral of the following:

$$\int\limits_{t,t'}{\frac{dt\,dt'}{\|x(t)-y(t')\|}}$$

I would be happy to get some hints.

Comment: What are you integrating with respect to?

Comment: @nayrb, sorry I forgot to put that however the more I think about it the more I get to the conclusion that it should be infinite.

Comment: Yes, it is infinite. It seems you are trying to compute the self-inductance of a square loop. Look at wiki page of [Inductance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance). In the section about self-inductance of simple electrical circuits, there is a complicated formula for a rectangular loop where the wire radius is small but finite.

Comment: @achillehui, no that was not the way I got to this problem. But it was pretty interesting that it exists in some other branch of science. I've got this in probability theory. Thanks a lot for letting me know such a connection.

Answer (score 0):

If the functions $x,y$  are Lipschitz, then for every $t'$ the integral over $t$ is infinite: roughly speaking, it contains a piece of $ \int \frac{ \,dx}{|x|}$ near zero. Hence the double integral is infinite too. It would be finite if the kernel was $\|t-t'\|^p$ with $p>-1$.

It should be possible to prove that the integral is infinite for any pair of homeomorphic parametrizations of the boundary, e.g., based on the differentiability of monotone functions almost everywhere.